# How to change value of child of firebase realtime database in function on stop and ondestroy I tried it but this not working. Please use kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

How to change value of child of firebase realtime database in function on stop and ondestroy I tried it but this not working. I had also used lifecycle method but it is deprecated. And another lifecycle method is not working.

Please give a solution to change value from online to offline in firebase realtime database after closing app.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a value to the database requires a network call, which can not be reliable done in `onStop` and `onDestroy` phases of the app's lifecycle.

If you want to write specific data when the app is closing/closed, consider using Firebase Realtime Database's built-in [`onDisconnect` handlers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#how-ondisconnect-works), which are precisely made for that purpose. They work by schedule a write operation, while the app **is** connected, that the server then executes when it detects that the client has disconnected.

Comment: In frustration of this problem finally I had shut down my computer but I will definitely use this method thanku

Comment: this is working fine whenever I close app and also remove it from background but it's not work whenever app is in backgroud. I want to change value whenever it go in backgroud

Comment: This works whenever Android closes the socket connections of the app, which it also does when the app has been backgrounded for a few minutes. Either way, if Android doesn't close the connection, you don't need to rely on `onDisconnect` for that situation - your code can detect the situation and perform its own writes.

Comment: Kindly, Thanks for helping but if I can write a code for this then I had doesn't ask the question here.

Comment: You asked about `onStop` and `onDestroy` and I explained *why* you can't handle those from your app, and how you can instead handle them. You them asked additionally in a comment about when the app is backgrounded, and I again explained how to handle that. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: If you have used whatsapp in past you have notice this when you come to the app it shows you online to others but if you just click home button(ATTENTION : - app is running in background).then you become offline. I want just like this in my app but .disconnect() is work when I destroy app. but THANK YOU.